# jQuery this mouseEnter and mouseLeave

Tags: jquery

I did search for the answer around stackoverflow but couldn't find something specific to the problem that I'm having.

I have multiple divs with the id "forum-cat", and I want it so that when you mouseEnter one of them, it adds the class "mEnter" and when you mouseLeave it removes the class.

This is my PHP:

```
echo '<div class="well" id="forum-cat">';
echo '<h3 style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="index?id=' . $row2['id'] . '">' . $row2['name'] . '</a></h3>';
echo '<p class="desc">' . $row2['description'] . '</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#forum-cat').mouseEnter(function() {
          $(this).addClass('mEnter');
     });
     $('#forum-cat').mouseLeave(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('mEnter');
     });
});
```

I'm not really experienced in jQuery :p thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't create multiple divs with the same ID. Javascript expects IDs to be unique, so when you add an event handler to the forum-cat ID, it'll only work for one of the divs. Use classes, which are suited for multiple elements, instead.

Comment: By the way, what does your mEnter class do? If its only purpose is to add a style through CSS, you can use the :hover pseudo-selector on the .forum-cat class in your CSS and apply the styles there, instead of adding a class through jQuery while the mouse is over the element.

Comment: All that class does is change the background-color for the hovered div.

Comment: Great, then you can do this on the CSS instead of using jQuery: `.forum-cat:hover { background-color: yourcolor; }`. Remember to change all your `id='forum-cat'` to `class='forum-cat'` to keep standard.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what's going on now, but this doesn't work either.. I changed the id="forum-cat" to class="forum-cat" but it still doesn't change. I don't even know what I'm doing wrong :s

Comment: Did you add the CSS declaration I wrote on the previous comment? Adding your color of choice, of course.

Comment: Yeah I did, and I fixed it now, thanks! I had to change around the order of the divs I had for some reason. Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome. Here's a working fiddle of the :hover pseudo-selector in case you want to check out an example. http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/Av5ER/

Comment: I posted my answer & thanked you in it. Yeah, it's much more simple than jQuery! Thanks again. :*

Answer (score 2):

You can only have ONE id of the same per page. So you'll need to use class instead. Change the html to `.forum-cat` instead of `#forum-cat`. And then the following should work fine.

Also, it's `mouseenter` not `mouseEnter`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.forum-cat').mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).addClass('mEnter');
     });
     $('.forum-cat').mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('mEnter');
     });
});
```

Comment: I changed the ids to divs, but still no success : -(

Comment: @StyleOnPC - Do you mean "ids to classes"?

Answer (score 1):

My solution, thanks to: EfrainReyes, was to use CSS (.forumcat:hover) rather than jQuery. Thank you everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: You're welcome :). Here's a working fiddle with an example of the :hover pseudo-selector http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/Av5ER/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like toggleClass and hover might serve you better here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.forum-cat').hover(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('mEnter');
     });
});
```

Comment: This answer assumes you've changed the IDs to classes as mentioned elsewhere. Having multiple elements with the same ID is bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "didn't work"? Did you encounter an error, not observe the intended behavior, etc?

Comment: Yes, sorry. There were no errors, whenever I hover over the div nothing changes. In the class, I changed the color, background-color, font-size, to make sure that it wasn't working.